# Open 2 Instances of VSCode on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to open 2 instances of VSCode on my mac. The thing is it works, except I can't get them to **appear on the dock at the same time**.

I tried the following (which works with other programs, except vscode):

```
open -n /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
```

Any clue?
Thanks!

Comment: any difference if you instead run `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app -n`?